# `parseInt` is not working as expected when special characters exists

Tags: javascript

i have `var value="10+10"` when i try to convert this using `parseInt(value)` to an int it is giving me `NaN`. Is their any option to convert a string if it has special characters in it?
The Result shoud be `20` or  simply `10+10`

Comment: So what result do you expect back? PS: `parseInt('10 + 10')` returns `10`

Comment: Expression evaluation is a complicated subject. What is the original problem you're solving that requires this?

Comment: i get dynamically a string consisting of `"10+10"` so i just need to solve that, it may come anything sub,add,multiplication

Comment: @SyedRasheed so why do you get an expression that you need to evaluate? Do you implement a calculator?

Comment: thanks @JaromandaX `eval` works :)

Comment: but `eval` is not the proper way to handle this?

Comment: I have removed the angularjs, arrays, javascript-events, and javascript-objects tags from the question, since nothing in the question title or body touches on those subjects at all. Also, I'm voting to close because you have not included the code needed to produce the claimed result: `parseInt("10+10")` does *not* return `NaN`, it returns the number `10` (because that is what it is *supposed to* do, even though it's not what you want it to do).

Comment: You have not explained the original problem, so it's not possible to suggest you a better solution.

Comment: @JaromandaX right, and now you talk about "trust" after you already suggested them `eval`, which they have used in their code and unlikely to revisit ever. Good job!

Comment: care factor < 0 and falling @zerkms

Comment: if you have `var value = "10+10"` ... where exactly is the trust issue @zerkms? if you write `var value="some function that sends all my banking details to india"` - then you deserve what you get if you eval that

Comment: @JaromandaX if you have a constant expression - you don't need an `eval` either, just do `var sum = 20;`

Comment: which makes the whole question irrelevant

Comment: @JaromandaX that's correct. That is the reason why one might ask about the real problem to be solved first, not just to try pick the low hanging fruit.

Answer (score 1):

you can use eval to evaluate string operations.
since parseInt doesn't recognize characters like `+` it will return the numbers until special characters.

as a example

`(parseInt("10+10")` print 10 and

`(parseInt("100+10")` print 100 and

```js
 
console.log(parseInt("10+10"))
console.log(parseInt("100+10"))

console.log(eval("10+10"))
console.log(eval("10*10"))
```

Comment: You *can* use `eval()` to evaluate a string, but it should not be recommended without cautioning the would-be user about not using it on untrusted/user-input data.